# assertRaises(AttributeError, ...) not working. Module 'myModule' has no attribute 'main' (Python Unit Test)

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, attributeerror

I'm new to Python. My first unit test doesn't work.

Here is my `telegram.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket
import sys
import urllib.parse

import certifi
import pycurl
from io import BytesIO

# telegram API key and chat id
TELEGRAM_API_KEY = 'xxx'
TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID = 'xxx'

DEBUG_MODE: bool = False


# stuff to run always here such as class/def
def main(msg):
    if not msg:
        print("No message to be sent has been passed.")
        exit(1)

    def debug(debug_type, debug_msg):
        if DEBUG_MODE:
            print(f"debug({debug_type}): {debug_msg}")

    def send_message(message):
        print("sending telegram...")

        c = pycurl.Curl()

        if DEBUG_MODE:
            c.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1)
            c.setopt(pycurl.DEBUGFUNCTION, debug)

        params = {
            'chat_id': TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID,
            'text': message
        }

        telegram_url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{TELEGRAM_API_KEY}/sendMessage?" + urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
        c.setopt(pycurl.CAINFO, certifi.where())
        storage = BytesIO()
        c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, storage)
        c.setopt(c.URL, telegram_url)
        c.perform()
        c.close()

        print(storage.getvalue())

    send_message(f"{socket.gethostname()}: {msg}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # stuff only to run when not called via 'import' here
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        main(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        print("No message to be sent has been passed.")
        exit(1)
```

I want to test this script. I can call this script directly from shell with command line argument oder can call this script in another python script like `telegram.main("Test Message")`.

My unit test doesn't work. I expect an AttributeError because I don't give the argument for `telegram.main()`.

Here is the unit test:

```
import unittest
import telegram
import subprocess


class TelegramTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """Tests for 'telegram.py'"""

    def test_empty_telegram(self):
        """call telegram directly without an argument"""
        self.assertRaises(AttributeError, telegram.main())

    def test_string_telegram(self):
        """call telegram directly with correct argument"""
        telegram.main("TästString...123*ß´´OK")
        self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The result of the first test case is:

> Error Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\unittest\case.py",
> line 60, in testPartExecutor
> yield   File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\unittest\case.py",
> line 676, in run
> self._callTestMethod(testMethod)   File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\unittest\case.py",
> line 633, in _callTestMethod
> method()   File "G:\Repositories\python\unittests\telegram.py", line 11, in test_empty_telegram
> self.assertRaises(AttributeError, telegram.main()) AttributeError: module 'telegram' has no attribute 'main'
>
> Ran 1 test in 0.003s
>
> FAILED (errors=1)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

What is the problem here? I think `telegram.main()` and `telegram.main("Test")` can't be found but why?

I want to test `telegram.main()` and I am asserting an AttributeError because I don't give an argument so the test should be passed.

Thank you.

### Update:

I changed the first test method to

```
def test_empty_telegram(self):
    """call telegram directly without an argument"""
    with self.assertRaises(AttributeError):
        telegram.main()
```

and it works. But the following test methods have the same errors.

```
def test_string_telegram(self):
    """call telegram directly with correct argument"""
    with self.assertRaises(SystemExit) as cm:
        telegram.main("TästString...123*ß´´OK")
        self.assertEqual(cm.exception.code, 0)
```

Output:

> Testing started at 22:43 ...
> C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
> C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.2\plugins\python\helpers\pycharm_jb_unittest_runner.py
> --target telegram.TelegramTestCase.test_string_telegram Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest
> telegram.TelegramTestCase.test_string_telegram in
> G:\Repositories\python\unittests
>
> Error Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\unittest\case.py",
> line 60, in testPartExecutor
> yield   File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\unittest\case.py",
> line 676, in run
> self._callTestMethod(testMethod)   File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\unittest\case.py",
> line 633, in _callTestMethod
> method()   File "G:\Repositories\python\unittests\telegram.py", line 17, in test_string_telegram
> telegram.main("TästString...123*ß´´OK") AttributeError: module 'telegram' has no attribute 'main'
>
> Ran 1 test in 0.003s
>
> FAILED (errors=1)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1
>
> Assertion failed
>
> Assertion failed
>
> Assertion failed

### Update 2

The problem was that I named my module `telegram.py`. The test file has got the same name in a subfolder. The problem is solved by renaming the test file. Thanks to the helping commentators!

Comment: `assertRaises` needs a function object as second argument, not the call result - better use `with self.assertRaises(AttributeError): telegram.main()`.

Comment: The first test method works now but the following not. The same error like in my inital post.

Comment: you have two files named `telegram.py` and so `import telegram` is importing the test module and not your target module

Comment: @AnthonySottile unbelievable... you're right! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As `assertRaises` needs a function object as second argument, not the call result, just add `lambda:` in front of `telegram.main()` like this:

```
def test_empty_telegram(self):
    self.assertRaises(AttributeError, lambda: telegram.main())
```